# Polynomials such that $f_n(x+y, xy) = x^n + y^n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

What is the pattern in the following polynomials? How can they be easily obtained?
\begin{align*}
   f_1(s, p) &= s \\
   f_2(s, p) &= s^2 - 2p \\
   f_3(s, p) &= s^3 - 3sp \\
   f_4(s, p) &= s^4-4 s^2 p+2 p^2 \\
   f_5(s, p) &= s^5-5 s^3 p+5 s p^2 \\
   f_6(s, p) &= s^6-6 s^4 p+9 s^2 p^2-2 p^3   \\
             &\vdots
\end{align*}
These polynomials express the sums of $n$th powers of two variables $x$ and $y$ in terms of their sum ($s$) and product ($p$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting $p=-1$, these are [Lucas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasPolynomial.html) [polynomials](https://oeis.org/wiki/Lucas_polynomials):

$$L_n(x) = 2^{-n} \left((x-\sqrt{x^2+4})^n + (x+\sqrt{x^2+4})^n  \right)$$

Your coefficients correspond to [OEIS A034807](https://oeis.org/A034807) and may be expressed in terms of Lucas numbers.

Thanks to Steven Stadnicki for him comment below pointing out that the $p$ powers can be inferred, so setting $p=-1$ is WLOG.

---

For completion:

By induction, we may prove that your sequence satisfies the relation
$$f_{n} = s f_{n-1} - p f_{n-2}$$
with $f_0=2$ and $f_1=s$.

We have seen that the base case $n=2$ works. Suppose the relation $f_{n} (x+y, xy)=x^n+y^n$ holds for integers below $n$. Then,

$$f_{n} (x+y, xy) = (x+y)(x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}) - xy (x^{n-2}+y^{n-2}) = x^n+y^n$$

Your sequence may thus be expressed generally as a [Lucas Polynomial Sequence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasPolynomialSequence.html):

$$f_n = 2^{-n} \left[\left(s+\sqrt{s^2-4p}\right)^n + \left(s-\sqrt{s^2-4p}\right)^n \right]$$

Comment: Note to OP: each term $s^ap^b$ in $f_n(s,p)$ has $a+2b=n$, so the polynomials are 'almost' homogeneous ($f_n(s,p^2)$ is a homogeneous polynomial) and so you don't lose any information by doing this.

Comment: Or, by the quadratic formula with $x^2 - sx + p = 0$ and similarly for $y$, we get $\{ x, y \} = \left\{ \frac{s \pm \sqrt{s^2-4p}}{2} \right\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can find recursively as:
$$
f_{n+1}(s,p)=s f_n(s,p)-p f_{n-1}(s,p)
$$

Answer (score 0):

CW answer. It means Country Western.

Note how the column with coefficients of $p^2$  has the integer part, 2, 5, 9, 14, 20, 27, 35, 44,  is quadratic in $n$

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
? f1 = s
%1 = s
? f2 = s^2 - 2 * p
%2 = s^2 - 2*p
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%3 = s^3 - 3*p*s
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%4 = s^4 - 4*p*s^2 + 2*p^2
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%5 = s^5 - 5*p*s^3 + 5*p^2*s
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%6 = s^6 - 6*p*s^4 + 9*p^2*s^2 - 2*p^3
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%7 = s^7 - 7*p*s^5 + 14*p^2*s^3 - 7*p^3*s
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%8 = s^8 - 8*p*s^6 + 20*p^2*s^4 - 16*p^3*s^2 + 2*p^4
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%9 = s^9 - 9*p*s^7 + 27*p^2*s^5 - 30*p^3*s^3 + 9*p^4*s
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%10 = s^10 - 10*p*s^8 + 35*p^2*s^6 - 50*p^3*s^4 + 25*p^4*s^2 - 2*p^5
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%11 = s^11 - 11*p*s^9 + 44*p^2*s^7 - 77*p^3*s^5 + 55*p^4*s^3 - 11*p^5*s
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%12 = s^12 - 12*p*s^10 + 54*p^2*s^8 - 112*p^3*s^6 + 105*p^4*s^4 - 36*p^5*s^2 + 2*p^6
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%13 = s^13 - 13*p*s^11 + 65*p^2*s^9 - 156*p^3*s^7 + 182*p^4*s^5 - 91*p^5*s^3 + 13*p^6*s
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%14 = s^14 - 14*p*s^12 + 77*p^2*s^10 - 210*p^3*s^8 + 294*p^4*s^6 - 196*p^5*s^4 + 49*p^6*s^2 - 2*p^7
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%15 = s^15 - 15*p*s^13 + 90*p^2*s^11 - 275*p^3*s^9 + 450*p^4*s^7 - 378*p^5*s^5 + 140*p^6*s^3 - 15*p^7*s
? f3 = s * f2 - p * f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3
%16 = s^16 - 16*p*s^14 + 104*p^2*s^12 - 352*p^3*s^10 + 660*p^4*s^8 - 672*p^5*s^6 + 336*p^6*s^4 - 64*p^7*s^2 + 2*p^8
?
```